# Is there a word for "default thinking"?

Tags: single-word-requests

As in, someone asks me how they should get fitter I immediately tell them to get active.

Default thinking? Default advice?

Comment: Not thinking "out-of-the-box".

Comment: Default thinking is technically the way to describe immediately telling someone something that came to mind first.

Comment: If you don't mean to be critical of your advice you could call it "commonsense" or "intuitive"; if you do mean to criticize it, you could characterize it as being offered "on autopilot."

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "default thinking"?  The example can be interpreted many ways (e.g. you're being helpful, you're being dismissive, you're being thoughtless, you're being sarcastic, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Try **hackneyed** or **stale** + whatever noun you like (advice, thinking, etc).

There are many ways to express this, and the best likely depends on context. Unoriginal, trite, thoughtless, lazy, etc. Otherwise the expression itself will be stale.

In the right context, you might even try the newspeak term "duckspeak," describing when someone speaks without thinking. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newspeak